# React Native Scrollable Tab View : Active tab backgroundColor

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-scrollable-tab-view (https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view).

Is it possible to set backgroundColor for Active tab?

I have tried set underline height = tab height like this:

```
  <ScrollableTabView
    initialPage={0}
    renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar />}
    tabBarUnderlineStyle={{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      height: 50,
    }}
  >
```

But the underline covered the tab text:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdZb2.gif)
.

Is there another way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Any luck with my solution @tak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid modifying the tab bar in the way you described as, even if you were to use a transparent background color, the active tab color would still overlay the text.

Instead, modify the `<DefaultTabBar />` component directly.

I've created a new default tab bar component for you by copying the `<DefaultTabBar />` component from source and modifying it to accept a new parameter called `activeBackgroundColor`.

Copy and paste [this](https://pastebin.com/B2Ct2Fqr) into a file called `DefaultTabBar.js`

Include this component and call as follows:

```
import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import DefaultTabBar from './DirYouPlacedThisIn/DefaultTabBar.js';

...

render() {
    return (
       <ScrollableTabView
          renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBarz activeBackgroundColor="#f1c40f" />}
       >
        ...
      </ScrollableTabView>
    );
  }
```

Troubleshooting: I'm using react-native-scrollable-tab-view@0.7.4. If the component I provided creates an error, you may have to reference the `<DefaulTabBar />` component in your `node_modules/react-native-scrollable-tab-view` folder. Apply the changes I made from my custom component (lines 23,41,51) to your own default component

Comment: Why did you define all method? Can I just extend DefaulTabBar and override some methods that I need to change?

Comment: It's what the documentation [suggest](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view#injecting-a-custom-tab-bar). Plus,  there wouldn't be a way to override the renderTab() method using a HOC and [inheritance](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/613#issuecomment-29280175) is frowned upon.

Comment: I see. Should I copy Button.(ios|android).js too? I've changed line 9 to `
import { Button, } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes. Copy over that file and it should work. Don't replace the line.

Comment: I've got an error: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
(at line 13)

Comment: If you are using React v15.5+, you'll need to use the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) package. Then change any `React.PropTypes` to `PropTypes`.

Comment: OK. thanks! I've changed your code to es6: https://pastebin.com/X2rvugZj . And this works fine! Please tell me If there is a mistake.

Comment: Just tested and it looks good! Here's how I'm calling the new component you created: https://pastebin.com/1EBCbakH

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered once you're satisfied :)

Comment: I did but I couldn't vote you up because my req is low :( Thank you!